# Is capturing a newly constructed object by const ref undefined behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, undefined-behavior

Is the following (contrived example) okay or is it undefined behavior:

```
// undefined behavior?
const auto& c = SomeClass{};

// use c in code later
const auto& v = c.GetSomeVariable();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is safe. Const ref prolongs the lifetime of temporary. The scope will be the scope of const ref.

> The [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a
>   const lvalue reference or to an rvalue reference (since C++11), see
>   [reference initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) for details.
>
> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to a subobject
>   thereof, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the
>   lifetime of the reference, with the following **exceptions**:
>
> - a temporary bound to a return value of a function in a return statement is not extended: it is destroyed immediately at the end of
>     the return expression. Such function always returns a dangling
>     reference.
> - a temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor initializer list persists only until the constructor exits, not as
>     long as the object exists. (note: such initialization is ill-formed as
>     of DR 1696).
> - a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists until the end of the full expression containing that function
>     call: if the function returns a reference, which outlives the full
>     expression, it becomes a dangling reference.
> - a temporary bound to a reference in the initializer used in a new-expression exists until the end of the full expression containing
>     that new-expression, not as long as the initialized object. If the
>     initialized object outlives the full expression, its reference member
>     becomes a dangling reference.
> - a temporary bound to a reference in a reference element of an aggregate initialized using direct-initialization syntax (parentheses)
>     as opposed to list-initialization syntax (braces) exists until the end
>     of the full expression containing the initializer. 
>     `struct A {
>       int&& r;
>     };
>     A a1{7}; // OK, lifetime is extended
>     A a2(7); // well-formed, but dangling reference`
>
> In general, the lifetime of a temporary cannot be further extended by "passing it
>   on": a second reference, initialized from the reference to which the
>   temporary was bound, does not affect its lifetime.

as [@Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph) pointed out (and see the last paragraph of above):

> "If `c.GetSomeVariable()` returns a reference to a local object or a reference that it is itself extending some object’s lifetime, lifetime extension does not kick in"

Comment: You should cite the source of that quote.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica done. I was looking for a better text.

Comment: It would be good to underline that this is only true for *values*. If `c.GetSomeVariable()` returns a *reference* to a local object or a reference that it is itself extending some object’s lifetime, lifetime extension does *not* kick in.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks! I added the exception too.

Answer (score 5):

There should be no issue here, thanks to [lifetime extension](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/). The newly constructed object will survive until the reference goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is perfectly safe: the binding to a `const` reference extends the lifetime of the temporary to the scope of that reference.

Note that the behaviour is not *transitive* though. For example, with

```
const auto& cc = []{
    const auto& c = SomeClass{};
    return c;
}();
```

`cc` dangles.

Answer (score 2):

**This is safe.**

> [`[class.temporary]/5`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#5): There are three contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the *full-expression*. *[..]*
>
> [`[class.temporary]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6): The third context is when a reference is bound to a temporary object. **The temporary object to which the reference is bound** or the temporary object that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound **persists for the lifetime of the reference** if the glvalue to which the reference is bound was obtained through one of the following: *[lots of things here]*

Answer (score 1):

It is safe in this specific case. Note however that not all temporaries are safe to capture by const reference... for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo {
    int member;

    Foo() : member(0) {
        printf("Constructor\n");
    }

    ~Foo() {
        printf("Destructor\n");
    }

    const Foo& method() const {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    {
        const Foo& x = Foo{};        // safe
        printf("here!\n");
    }
    {
        const int& y = Foo{}.member; // safe too (special rule for this)
        printf("here (2)!\n");
    }
    {
        const Foo& z = Foo{}.method(); // NOT safe
        printf("here (3)!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The reference obtained for `z` is NOT safe to use because the temporary instance will be destroyed at the end of full expression, before reaching the `printf` statement. Output is:

```
Constructor
here!
Destructor
Constructor
here (2)!
Destructor
Constructor
Destructor
here (3)!
```